# Footer sem rolamento(overflow hidden)

Tags: html, html5

Olá, estou criando um código html com bootstrap em que eu estou adicionando um footer, mas quando eu coloco o footer, minha pagina adiciona uma barra de rolamento para poder visualizar o footer... é apenas um copyright e eu gostaria que ele ficasse na mesma tela e sem o overflow(barra de rolamento)... alguem poderia me ajudar?

```css
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, #fff, #aaa);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.card {
    border-radius: 15px;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="password"] {
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    outline: none;
    padding: 8px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:focus {
    border-color: dodgerBlue;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 dodgerBlue;
}

.inputWithIcon input[type="text"]:focus + i,
.inputWithIcon input[type="password"]:focus + i {
    color: dodgerBlue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container h-100">
  <div class="row h-100 align-items-center">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col-5">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title text-center mb-4 mt-1">Login</h4>
          <hr>
          <form method="" id="form" autocomplete="off">
            <!--Inputs para preenchimento dos dados do usuário-->
            <div class="">
              <input name="numeroSerie" class="form-control" autofocus type="text">
            </div>

            <div class="">
              <input id="user" class="form-control" autofocus type="text">
              
            </div>

            <div class="">
              <input id="pass" class="form-control" autofocus type="password">
            </div>
            
            <label for="remember_pass"><input type="checkbox" id="remember_pass"> Lembrar senha</label>

            <br>

            <label for="remember_login"><input type="checkbox" id="remember_login"> Permanecer conectado </label>

            <hr>

            <div class="form-group">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block">Acessar</button>
            </div>
            
          </form>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col"></div>
  </div>
  <footer class="page-footer font-small blue">

    <!-- Copyright -->
    <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">
      © 2019 Copyright:
       Samuel
    </div>
    <!-- Copyright -->

  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta descontar da altura do `container` a altura do `footer`. Repare que quando vc coloca a classe `h-100` do Bootstrap vc deixa o `container` com 100% da altura, e ai somando os 56px do `footer` acaba gerando a barra de rolagem.

Minha sugestão é criar a classe `.cotainer-footer` e usar o `calc()` do CSS para fazer o ajuste tipo `height: calc(100% - 56px) !important;` e no HTML seu `container` ficaria `<div class="container container-footer">` removendo o `h-100`. *Tem outras opções para fazer isso, vc pode usar `position:absolute` ou `fixed` e `bottom:0`, mas ai vai de cada um, eu preferi fazer assim...*

Veja como fica, **execute em página toda**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title>Page Title</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
 
html, body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}


body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, #fff, #aaa);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.card {
    border-radius: 15px;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="password"] {
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    outline: none;
    padding: 8px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:focus {
    border-color: dodgerBlue;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 dodgerBlue;
}

.inputWithIcon input[type="text"]:focus + i,
.inputWithIcon input[type="password"]:focus + i {
    color: dodgerBlue;
}
.container-footer {
 height: calc(100% - 56px) !important;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container container-footer">
  <div class="row h-100 align-items-center">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col-5">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title text-center mb-4 mt-1">Login</h4>
          <hr>
          <form method="" id="form" autocomplete="off">
            <!--Inputs para preenchimento dos dados do usuário-->
            <div class="">
              <input name="numeroSerie" class="form-control" autofocus type="text">
            </div>

            <div class="">
              <input id="user" class="form-control" autofocus type="text">
              
            </div>

            <div class="">
              <input id="pass" class="form-control" autofocus type="password">
            </div>
            
            <label for="remember_pass"><input type="checkbox" id="remember_pass"> Lembrar senha</label>

            <br>

            <label for="remember_login"><input type="checkbox" id="remember_login"> Permanecer conectado </label>

            <hr>

            <div class="form-group">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block">Acessar</button>
            </div>
            
          </form>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col"></div>
  </div>
  <footer class="page-footer font-small blue">

    <!-- Copyright -->
    <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">
      © 2018 Copyright:
      <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/education/bootstrap/"> MDBootstrap.com</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Copyright -->

  </footer>
</div>
 
</body>
</html>
```